# Android Class.getGenericSuperclass returns java.lang.Object

Tags: android, generics, reflection, superclass

I am trying to read generic info from a class. Here is what I am doing: first of all I have a class EntityHelper. Somewhere inside it I want to see what is actually that T.
I know this can be done with:

```
(Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

but what method getGenericSuperClass returns is java.lang.Object - which is not correct since I know T is something else, for example DummyEntity.

Android platform I use is 7. Is this some kind of a bug or I am missing something important?

Comment: how can you cast `java.lang.reflect.Type` to `Class<T>`?

Comment: Compiler doesn't object and it works in runtime. For example: (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) f.getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]; where f is java.lang.Field.
Class implements Type - maybe it is not nice, but it works.

Comment: `Class implements Type`- i missed it.

Comment: how can you get the actual generic type? generics in java is a compile time mechanism([Type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)).

Comment: only way to achieve this effect is to save the `Class<T>` type as a member variable.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can not get the generic type of the argument. Generics are implemented using a technique called [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Only way to achieve this effect is to save the `Class<T>` type( i.e. 
Use [Class Literals as Runtime-Type Tokens](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html) ).

Comment: It is implemented using type erasure but the information about generic type is kept. If that wouldn't be true, method java.lang.Class#getGenericSuperclass() wouldn't make much sense. Little code fragment I posted in one of my comments on the question retrieves the actual type of objects contained in the list (which uses generics) and it is working fine, hence this can be done.

Comment: @ezamur: compiler writes the type(T) as comment in the class file.

Comment: @ezamur: do you want to see the type that is declared(like T,S...)?

Comment: @ezamur: print the `java.lang.Field` and see the type.

Comment: Ok, this might be trickier than I expected. My approach doesn't work, as you already said, unfortunately. On the other hand, if I use it on a member variable, it works. For example, if we have a class containing property List<String> aList, next fragment of code will give us right answer to the question what is the type of objects in the list: ((ParameterizedType)getClass().getField("aList").getGenericType()).getActualTypeParameters()[0]. Trouble is I cannot find a way to do the same on a class argument. I guess I will have to accept your answer. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: @ezamur:`Little code fragment I posted in one of my comments on the question retrieves the actual type of objects contained in the list (which uses generics) and it is working fine` - because compiler adds appropriate **cast** for you.

Comment: @ezamur:`if we have a class containing property List<String> aList, next fragment of code will give us right answer to the question what is the type of objects in the list:` - because compiler saves the actual type signature `Ljava/lang/String` as a comment in class file. If it of type `S`, then it would be `TS`. `L` means `class type` and `T` means `generic type`.